# Revert all merged commits after pushing them to remote

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-revert

I have the next case.
There are two branches:

- **dev**- our development branch that includes all the current results;
- **ml_DEL-1049** - my working branch which was created for the particular task.
  While I was working in my **ml_DEL-1049** branch I merged **dev** into it from time to time. And finally, I merged my branch **ml_DEL-1049** into the **dev** branch. You can see it in the pic.
  [image]

Now, I have to revert this merge. But when I try to revert the last commit (merge commit) I revert only changes from this particular commit (changes of formBlock.vue file). But not all the previous commits from my working branch.
As an additional condition: I'm going to merge the results of **ml_DEL-1049** to the **dev** branch later.

If I understand properly, I should revert merging and then when I need to merge it again I will revert the revert commit. But how to perform it? Is there any way to not search for all commits to revert in my **ml_DEL-1049** branch?

This question contains two parts:

1. How to revert it now?
2. How to merge results to dev after reverting in the future?

Note: on the screenshot, there are commits from the **dev** branch filtered by the message 'DEL-1049'. All the commits have been pushed to remote and there are already many commits after and between them.

The result of `git log --graph --oneline`:
[image]

*Sorry for the pictures, I can't get text data from the Amazon Workspace

Comment: `git log --graph --oneline` providing the branches involved will be much simpler to understand. Can you replace the image for it in the question? You are not a newbie in the site but a friendly reminder just in case; _as text_.

Comment: @eftshift0 , thank you, i'll add a result of git log --graph --oneline. But unfortunately I work from Amazon Workspace and any copying from it is disabled so I can't provide text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reverting just the last commit (a regular commit) of a branch, git will *not* revert changes from commits that are behind it. If you need to revert changes that came in as part of a merge, then you need to revert the merge commit itself (which will require you to use the `-m` option of revert).

Then, about *how to be able to commit that same stuff again*: I think it would be much simpler to handle if you had kept a straight no-merges branch for your development because then it's very simple to *rewrite* history of your branch so that, to git, it's all new stuff that hasn't been merged *ever*... if you have merges pulling stuff from the upstream branch, then it's a little tricky and probably the easiest way to do it would be to revert the reversal, as you propose.

Comment: I think maybe cherry-picking commits from the feature branch will do the trick.

Comment: After they have been merged? Even if reverted? That won't hold water cause git will refuse to get them in, as they are merged already. You would need to _rewrite history_ (as I was saying that is easier to do if it were a straight line) so that git does not complain.